# Use proper string literal in templated function in C++

Tags: c++, string, templates, string-literals

I have a function, that is templated to match every std::basic_string instantiation:

```
template <typename _valueType>
void addFoo(std::basic_string<_valueType>& string_)
{
    string_ += "foo";
}
```

I want `"foo"` to be `_valueType`-dependent literal. I would like not to use specialization, because in the actual project I have whole class templated and it would be a lot of work.
 I am currently using `if constexpr` in function body, but problems start, when I have function taking default parameter like this:

```
template <typename _valueType>
void foo(_valueType const delimiter_ = '.');
```

Comment: There are an unbounded number of `basic_string` instantiations that could exist.  You are also missing a template argument for `basic_string` -- it takes 2 not 1 type (the second is a traits class):  I could write a `basic_string<double, SomeTraits>`.  In addition, one of yours cases use a `'.'` (single quote), the other a string `"foo"` double quote.  Please be less vague, what does your actual problem entail?

Comment: I decided to support only the default traits, but if there is strong argument against this method, please inform me.  My actual problem is described in the question: I want to use proper string/character literal depending on which string instantiation takes place.

Comment: For some reason you ignored my first sentence.  I'll make it longer: `basic_string<char16_t>`, `basic_string<char>` `basic_string<unsigned char>` `basic_string<char32_t>` `basic_string<wchar_t>` are all possible `basic_string` types.  I have no idea what `_valueType` can vary over; while I expect you do.  If there is no limit on what it can vary over, there are different good answers than if (say) you support exactly 2.

Comment: I will limit it to the types you mentioned using SFINAE, because I want it to support all these. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you only support `char` and `wchar_t`.  If you want to support a longer enumerated list of types, you can also do that.  This doesn't work for a non-locally enumerated list of types.

```
template<class Index, class...Args>
decltype(auto) dispatch( Index, Args&&... args ) {
  return std::get<Index{}>( std::forward_as_tuple( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
}
```

This is a neat little helper that lets you compile-time dispatch between any number of arguments.

Now in your class define this:

```
template<class Char, class WChar>
static decltype(auto) pick(Char&& c, WChar&& w) {
  using is_wchar_t = std::is_same<_valueType, wchar_t>;
  return dispatch( is_wchar_t{}, std::forward<Char>(c), std::forward<WChar>(w) );
}
```

you can now do this:

```
template <typename _valueType>
void addFoo(std::basic_string<_valueType>& string_)
{
  string_ += pick( "foo", L"foo" );
}
```

if you dislike the DRY failure

```
#define BOTH_CHARTYPE(...) __VA_ARGS__, L __VA_ARGS__

template <typename _valueType>
void addFoo(std::basic_string<_valueType>& string_)
{
  string_ += pick( BOTH_CHARTYPE("foo") );
}
```

or somesuch (might need more macro magic to make the `L` attach to the `""` properly).

This is written in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), but it can be adapted for [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) relatively easily; replace `Index{}` with `Index::value` and replace `decltype(auto)` with a `->decltype()` clause.

```
template<class...Ts>
struct types { using type=types; };
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

template<class T, class Types>
struct type_index;
template<class T, class...Ts>
struct type_index<T, types<T, Ts...>>:index_t<0> {};
template<class T, class T0, class...Ts>
struct type_index<T, types<T0, Ts...>>:index_t<
  type_index<T, types<Ts...>>{}+1
>{};

using char_types = types<char, wchar_t, char16_t, char32_t>;

template<class T>
using char_index = type_index<T, char_types >;

#define ALL_CHAR_TYPES(...) __VA_ARGS__, L __VA_ARGS__, u __VA_ARGS__, U __VA_ARGS__

template<class T, class...Chars>
decltype(auto) pick(Chars&&...chars) {
  return dispatch( char_index< T >{}, std::forward<Chars>(chars) );
}

void addFoo( std::basic_string<_valueType>& string_ ) {
  string_ += pick<_valueType>( ALL_CHAR_TYPES("foo") );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is probably the best answer. I will try to expand it to support char16_t and char32_t.
I am using C++17 right now :)

Comment: @razzorflame use `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, X>`, where `X` is `0` through `3` based on which type, instead of `std::is_same`.

Comment: I don't really know how can I specify which integral is bound to which type.

Comment: @razzorflame sketch of 4 type dispatch added.  There may be typos.  `ALL_CHAR_TYPES` may need additional macros to append the `L` to the `"foo"` properly depending on compiler.

Comment: `char_index` is missing `using`  and `index_t` has typo in template probably. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use an external class with specialization:

```
template <class>
struct basic_string_literals;

template <>
struct basic_string_literals<char> {
    constexpr char * foo = "foo";
    constexpr char delim = '.'
};

template <typename _valueType>
void addFoo(std::basic_string<_valueType>& string_)
{
    string_ += basic_string_literals<_valueType>::foo;
}

template <typename _valueType>
void foo(_valueType const delimiter_ = basic_string_literals<_valueType>::delim);
```

This way you don't have to specialize each function / class templated on `_valueType`, you only have a single point of specialization.

Comment: This is nice method I didn't think of. Unfortunately it forces me to put every literal in that `basic_string_literals` specialization. However, if no other option is available I will use yours.