# String literal that depends on the template type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that can parse strings (dates). I want to be able to parse normal as well as wide strings:

```
MyClass x;
x.parse("2018-02-27");
x.parse(L"2018-02-27");
```

Since the code to parse a normal string and a wide string is basically the same, it makes sense to use a template:

```
template<typename CharT>
void parse(const CharT *str)
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, for parsing I am going to use the [get_time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) function. It takes the `fmt` parameter, which is of type `const CharT *`, and for which I would like to provide a string literal. It must be a normal or wide string literal, depending on the template type parameter:

```
template<typename CharT>
void parse(const CharT *str)
{
    tm date;
    basic_istringstream<CharT> date_stream{str};
    date_stream >> get_time(&date, ("%Y-%m-%d" or L"%Y-%m-%d", but how to choose??) );
    // ...
}
```

I am only interested in two template instantiations: char and wchar_t. I tried to use non-type template parameters, but did not manage to get anything that compiles.

What is the most elegant way to implement the function/template?

Comment: If you only want two types why not just overload the function for each type?

Comment: I do not count (almost) copy-pasting my code twice as "elegant". Besides, I would have two functions to maintain.

Comment: Duplicate: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771828/use-proper-string-literal-in-templated-function-in-c)

Comment: I agree about the duplicate, but even the first answer to this question looks better.

Comment: Another potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261673/templates-and-string-literals-and-unicode

Comment: I like both answers from Quentin and Martin Bonner and would accept both if I could. But having just a (templated) variable instead of a traits class is a bit more light-weight, in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first attempt to shoehorn `if constexpr` in there didn't go well, but a variable template looks fine:

```
template <typename CharT>
constexpr CharT const *timeFmt;

template <>
constexpr auto timeFmt<char> = "%Y-%m-%d";

template <>
constexpr auto timeFmt<wchar_t> = L"%Y-%m-%d";

template <typename CharT>
void parse(const CharT *str)
{
    std::tm date;
    std::basic_istringstream<CharT> date_stream{str};
    date_stream >> std::get_time(&date, timeFmt<CharT>);
    // ...
}
```

---

For the record, here is the ugly thing that came out of my first try:

```
template<typename CharT>
void parse(const CharT *str)
{
    std::tm date;
    std::basic_istringstream<CharT> date_stream{str};
    date_stream >> std::get_time(&date, []{
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<CharT, wchar_t>)
            return L"%Y-%m-%d";
        else
            return "%Y-%m-%d";
    }());
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If you OP want to use this, make sure you use compiler with C++17 support. Also, the templated `timeFmt` can be constexpr.

Comment: @razzorflame variable templates are C++14 though :)

Comment: Aww yes, sorry. I was talking about `if constexpr` ;)

Comment: Same here, shouldn't `CharT const * const timeFmt;` be preferred to avoid modification?

Answer (score 3):

Add a traits class:

```
template <typename CharT>
struct format {
    static const CharT* const v;
};

template<> const char* const format<char>::v="%Y-%m-%d";
template<> const wchar_t* const format<wchar_t>::v=L"%Y-%m-%d";
```

then use as:

```
date_stream >> get_time(&date, format<CharT>::v);
```

If you were feeling ambitious, you could merge the actual duplicated format into a `#define` (and then use token pasting to glue an `L` on the front where necessary) - but actually, I think that's more machinery than it's worth.

Comment: This is better expressed than my (now deleted) answer, but: 1) I guess you meant `static const CharT* v`. 2) I think it should be declared as `static const CharT* const v;` (and then defined accordingly), to make sure the traits are not modified by the program.

Comment: @jdehesa: In both cases: yes, absolutely! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Besides *variable templates* and *class templates*, a *function template* will do as well:

```
template<typename T> const T* get_format_str();
```

Then, the corresponding specializations for both `char` and `wchar_t`:

```
template<> const char*    get_format_str<char>()    { return "%Y-%m-%d"; }
template<> const wchar_t* get_format_str<wchar_t>() { return L"%Y-%m-%d"; }
```

Use this function template in your `parse()` function template as:

```
date_stream >> get_time(&date, get_format_str<TChar>());
```

The advantages to this approach are:

- It only requires C++98 (for variable templates you need C++14).
- The pointer to the literal string can't be modified (only the copy of that pointer returned by the function can be modified).